# How to save Response then Output to the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application I have the user enter a number then once that number is entered send a response to the allotted space on the screen. How can I save multiple response to be randomly generated to the designated area?

Comment: Your question should be of the style `What is wrong with my solution?` *NOT* `Here is my problem, what is the solution?`

Answer (score -1):

Create a `NSMutableArray` and add the numbers there.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//add the number
[array addObject: number];
```

Now you can randomly choose numbers from the array and display them.

```
int number = [array objectAtIndex: 1];
```